# FGLRX 3D won't work

Tags: ati, catalyst

I have followed all the steps to get FGLRX Catalyst 12.8 installed. It seems to be installed, but I getting terrible distortions on my screen: [image]

And I can only access Unity 2D. Any thoughts on fixing this so I can use 3D Unity?

Answer (score 0):

You should use open source driver `xserver-xorg-video-ati` since `fglrx` doesn't work well.

I used `fglrx` before and direct rendering didn't work.